# Cannot access a closed stream when uploading to AWS S3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to upload a file into AWS S3 from my .NET core application.

I create a PDF of type `byte[]` and I pass it to the following function:

```
public async Task<S3Response> UploadFileAsync(string bucketName, byte[] file)
{
    try
    {
        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
        var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
            PartSize = 6291456,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.NoACL,
            Key = "Test.pdf"
        };

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(file))
        {
            fileTransferUtilityRequest.InputStream = ms;
        }

        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        return new S3Response
        {
            Message = e.Message,
            Status = e.StatusCode
        };
    }
}
```

The error that my catch handler is triggering is:

> Cannot access a closed stream

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `using` statement causes the `MemoryStream` you've created to be closed before you attempt to pass it through to `UploadAsync`. Instead, call `UploadAsync` from *inside* your `using` block:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(file))
{
    fileTransferUtilityRequest.InputStream = ms;
    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
}
```